# WS2016 Essentials Remote desktop limitations

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2016, windows-server-essentials

As far as I know, I won't be able to use RDS under WS2016 Essentials edition (only the Gateway role). Is there any workaround to this using Multipoint or something so my users can work in the office with their own session on the server (just like a desktop)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Is there any workaround to this` - Yes, purchase a Windows edition and CAL's that supports your business needs and your business process.

Comment: Nice workaround XD. This is, definitely, the only one. I will tell the buyer he got confused and wasted money for nothing. Thanks

Comment: Clearly you're asking how to violate the EULA, so no there isn't a workaround other than to purchase the appropriate version/edition to meet the business needs.

Comment: @joeqwerty no, I was not. I was wondering if there is any legal software allowing this. After the question I read about multipoint but realized it relies on RDS too so it won't work. But I just didn't know if there was some solution for this scenario I was not aware of as I am not a WS expert. So, no, I am not trying/intending/wanting to violate EULA. In fact I have already said this person that he made a mistake and has to buy a new edition.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. My point being that the only "legal" method or software would be from Microsoft, and obviously they didn't intend that or they would have included that functionality in the OS and the EULA. Any other method or software that accomplishes this would be in violation of the EULA and wouldn't therefore be "legal".

Comment: You are right!. But the more I read, the more it seems to me Microsoft hide this conciously. There are lots of people around who did not find a response about whether or not RDS would work with Essentials. That is a pity to say the least... I will try to believe this was unintentional, but it does not make small bussinesses life easier I am afraid (specially taking into account most of the time such bussinesses do not have a computer staff).